# PHP DATE function not working correct and date goes back to 1970

Tags: php, date, datetime

Here is my function

```
public function test($input, $duration){

        $input = date_create($input);
        $month =  date_format($input,'m-Y');

        $monthsArray[] = array(
                'month' => $month,
            );

        for($i=0; $i<$duration; $i++){

            $monthsArray[]= array(

                'month' => date('m-Y', strtotime("$i months", strtotime($month))),

                );
        }

        var_dump($monthsArray);
    }
```

Here is my input,

```
test(05-2016,3);
```

result should be like this,

> 05-2016 06-2016 07-2016 08-2016

But this function returns

> 05-2016 01-1970 02-1970 03-1970

Comment: The date functions return Jan 1, 1970 when the input you give it is not a valid date. (Read the documentation). So, start there. Make ABSOLUTELY CERTAIN that are passing in a valid date and not something like `05-2016` which is actually `-2011`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can use like this

```
<?php
function test($dt,$months){
  echo "\n".$dt;
  for($i=1;$i<=$months;$i++){
    $increseby =  "+"."$i";
    echo "\n".date('m-Y',strtotime('1-'.$dt." $increseby month"));
  }
}
test('05-2016',3);
?>
```

Check here : https://eval.in/570870

Answer (score 2):

Your input date is not in a valid format and also needs to be wrapped in quotes since it ids a string. otherwise you are subtracting 2016 from 5. If you are going to use the m-Y format you need to use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to parse that date:

```
<?php

function test($input, $duration){

    $date= DateTime::createFromFormat('m-Y', $input);
    $monthsArray = [$input];

    for($i=0; $i<$duration; $i++){
         $date->modify('+1 month');
         $monthsArray[] = $date->format('m-Y');
    }

    var_dump($monthsArray);
}

test('05-2016',3);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/570874)

I removed your usage of `strtotime()` as it is not needed or recommended for date manipulation.

Also, keep in mind that this code will break at the end of the month due to the fact that not all months have 30 or 31 days.